# Normalized data on a rolling window

Tags: r, normalization, dlm

I have a whole set of data on `[0,T]` with an observation variable `y(t)`, and a feature `x(t)`, the two being univariates with no missing data.

For a given period `[t, t+h]`, I am applying a dynamic linear regression:

```
y(t) = a(t) + b(t) * x(t) + w(t)   
a(t) = a(t-1) + w_a(t)
b(t) = b(t-1) + w_b(t)
```

Where `w, w_a, w_b` are the variance of the last term on these `3` lines (following a centered normal distribution).

What matters is that for window `[0, h]`, I normalize my data (x, y) - aka `zero mean` and `1 std` - and then will have a series of estimated parameters `a` and `b` after maximum likehood estimation:

```
time   a     b
   0   0     0
   1   0.41  0.72
   ...
   h-1 0.432 0.55
   h   0.435 0.567
```

I am interested in the last couple `a(h), b(h)` giving the intercept and the slope.

Then I take as training set `x(1), x(2) ... x(h+1)` and `y(1), y(2), .., y(h+1)`, normalize thse two series, and have as well some best estimations for the parameters `a` and `b`.
I take parameters `a(h+1)` and `b(h+1)`.

And so on. By rolling the window, I thus have a set of slopes `b(h), b(h+1), ..., b(T)` and intercept `a(h), a(h+1), ..., a(T)`

However the normalization differs between each rolling windows. So that I am not sure at all it is a good way to deduce some behaviour about the time series `a` and `b` of the "last estimation".

What would be the best method:

- still perform some analysis on `a` and `b` timeseries despite `(x,y)` normalisation is different on each window?
- apply the above by normalizing the data on each window `[t, t+h]` with the means/std of `y` and `x` on **[0, T]**?
- applying the above without normalizing the data?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize"? Are `a(t)` and `b(t)` OLS estimates based on $\{ (y_i,x_i), i \le t \}$, or something else? What's the purpose of this whole exercise?

Comment: By normalize I mean that I take each dataset on the window [t, t+h], where t goes over [0,T-h] and I retrieve the mean/divide per the std on each window. I edited the question since you're right, it's unclear.

Comment: Why do you want/need to normalize? For situations like these, where you need to change the sample, it seems really counterproductive. (May be you can go back and edit again :) ).

Comment: I should have mentionned that if I do not normalize, there are some numerical errors in optim in R dlm package. Indeed Y and X have different magnitude (Y around 100000 and X around 300).

Comment: Normalize by a fixed constant, then. Divide Y by 100000 and X by 300.

Comment: @StasK, thank you not a bad idea despite it seems a little bit random to me (not real justification apart experimental). The problem were the seeds, so I performed a seed competition to take the best one which are non failing. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
  zscore <- function(stock){
      # 30 day moving average 
      mavg_30 = (filter(stock, rep(1/30, 30), sides=1))
      # current value
      current = tail(stock, 1)
      # 30 day standard deviation
      std_30 = rollapply(stock, width = 30, FUN = sd)
      if(std_30 > 0){
        return((current - mavg_30)/std_30 )
        }
      }
```

this should do it

```
    zscore <- function(stock){
     # 30 day moving average
     mavg_30 = rollapply(stock, width=30, FUN=mean)
     # current value
     current = head(stock, 1)
     # 30 day standard deviation
     std_30 = rollapply(stock, width = 30, FUN = sd)
       if(std_30 > 0){
         return((current - mavg_30)/std_30 )
     }
    }
```

this would be another way